# How to signin on a web app properly if already signedin with Google somewhere on the web?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm making a web application using JavaScript.
I'm able to signin, signout with Google account and even to read/write file from Google Drive, but now I have found a weird exception.

Here how I can reproduce the exception:

1. I open Chrome with empty chace
2. I signin on Google Drive
3. I run the debug of my web app from Visual Studio (the web app is not published yet, so you can't test it)

now the web app seems to signin with the same Google account and to start to get a file from Google Drive (the one I want), but the process is interrupted in some way.
I have made some checks in the code to be sure that the web app is able to get the file or return an error, but only sometimes I get an "Error code 0", while most of the times I don't get any error and no file is retrieved.

I'm almost sure that something is wrong using Google API, but I don't know what.
When I run the web app (in the case above) the signin button of Google calls automatically the following function:

```
function checkAuth() {
gapi.auth.authorize(
    {
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPES,
        'immediate': true
    },
    handleAuthResult);
}
```

so my web app seems signedin, but it doesn't work.

Actually I have found a solution, but in my opinion it is a bad one: if my web app doesn't have any important data >> and I'm signed in with Google somewhere on the web >> I call a "signout()" function.

So if I signin again in my web app everything works as it should.

**Can you give me a better solution, especially avoiding the "signout" followed by another "signin" that I'm actually using?**

Comment: I have found the problem... If I open my web app after I have already signedin with Google somewhere on the web, Google in some way automatically signin my web app and after few milliseconds the "onSignIn()" function is called, so it is like a double signin that makes blocking the nextcode. Now I don't understand why there is a double authentication.